CORS Error with Delete Functionality on Live Server: Works Locally but Not on Live Laravel Website
I’m working on a Laravel project where users can delete reviews through their dashboard. The delete functionality works perfectly in localhost, but after deploying the application to my live server (InfinityFree), I encountered a CORS error when attempting to delete a review.
Website: [http://book-reviews.lovestoblog.com/]1
Issue: When a user attempts to delete a review from their dashboard, the following CORS error occurs:
my-reviews:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://errors.infinityfree.net/errors/403/' (redirected from 'http://book-reviews.lovestoblog.com/account/delete-myreview') from origin 'http://book-reviews.lovestoblog.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.Understand this error
jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2 
    
DELETE https://errors.infinityfree.net/errors/403/ net::ERR_FAILED

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this error?
